# Newly added angular 2 component doesn't work; it's properly added to app.module.js

Tags: angular

I created a new angular 2 project with `ng new hello` and `ng build`. Then using `ng serve`, I checked it works well showing 'app works!'.

Next, I added a new component with `ng g component hello`. The next one is `app.module.ts` which is automatically modified.

```
...
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello/hello.component';//<--here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   HelloComponent//<--here
  ],
...
```

Component part of `hello.component.ts` is like this. `hello.component.html` has a default html source.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello.component.css']
})
```

Then I finally added `<hello>Loading!!!</hello>` in `index.html` and ran the project with `ng serve` again but `<hello>` tag only shows "Loading!!!".

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: What do you get in your terminal? usually there are useful reports about bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not add `<hello>` tag in `index.html` add it in `app.component.html` your hello component is `child/directive`

**or you can use**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { HelloComponent } from './hello/hello.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HelloComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HelloComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: `<hello>` is a `shadow dom`  or component which you are not exporting from your `AppModule` if you export it via NgModule you can use it in index.html :)